# IPtables reset on reboot, how do I tell what is causing this

Tags: rhel, iptables, iptables-persistent

Using RHEL, and I have had some "Cyber Security" people work on my server.  I'm now using this server in a completely closed environment with no outward network connection, and would like my iptables set to completely off.  I have used these commands:

```
chkconfig iptables off
service iptables save
service iptables stop

chkconfig ip6tables off
service ip6tables save
service ip6tables stop
```

**The Issue**

Every time I restart the server the iptables are back on their incredibly restrictive settings.  Am I not doing something correctly, or do they have a script that could be running and resetting the iptables settings.  If there is a script, how could I figure out where this is coming from to disable it.

Comment: Thank you, that has temporarily fixed the problem, and I'll continue looking for the script that is causing the problem (I've already checked the cron jobs.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stopping `iptables` from starting during bootup using `chkconfig` would normally solve your problem, however since you mentioned that you had some "Cyber Security" people work on your server it's possible that `iptables` is configured to start using a non-standard method. Adding commands to the file `/etc/rc.local` is one such method.  Any commands in the file are executed during bootup so it's possible the `iptables` commands are in there.  You can try searching through all of your system's initialization scripts for `iptables` commands using:

```
$ sudo grep -r iptables /etc/rc*
```

or even one level higher

```
$ sudo grep -r iptables /etc*
```

If you can't find where the ruleset is being loaded from, you can look at the system's default ruleset `/etc/sysconfig/iptables` and compare it to the loaded rules using:

```
$ sudo iptables -vnL
```

If the rules in the file are the rules that are loaded upon reboot, then configure your ruleset how you want it and overwrite the file using `iptables-save`

```
as root:
# iptables-save > /etc/sysconfig/iptables
```

That won't completely solve your problem but it will give you more control in the meantime.

Comment: I set the rules as I wanted them, which is essentially no rules, and then ran the iptables-save > /etc/sysconfig/iptables, and it blanked out that file (which seems ok, but I'm not sure).  When I restarted the system, now the iptables rules are back where the way I don't want them, and the iptables file in /etc/sysconfig is still empty.  Does that seem odd?

Comment: @Slimmons The ruleset can be saved anywhere, `/etc/sysconfig/iptables` is just the default location.  You might be able to override what's being loaded automatically.  If you save a ruleset and load it using `/etc/rc.local` that could work.  You might also want to see if any firewall software was recently installed that you could have overlooked.

Answer (score 3):

I would look at your startup scripts, most likely `/etc/rc.d/rc.local`, and find out where the iptables startup rules are coming from.

To flush rules from all `filter` chains, you can do `iptables -t filter -F`.